# Why can I not save a PHP Form Variable binding in Dreamweaver CS6?

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I asked this question on Adobe's member forums earlier, but it seems getting any responses over there is is pretty difficult. Their website has been so slow today it's borderline unusable.

I'm attempting to add a form variable binding to a PHP document, but after each time I open the menu, type in my name and press OK, it does not show up in my Bindings box.

Here is where it's happening:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR0QA.png]

and then nothing happens from that:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqhEx.png]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Or what I haven't done yet? Does this look like a bug?

Not sure if I described the problem in enough detail. Any responses are greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I humbly suggest to drop DW and start coding in a better IDE (Aptana, Eclipse, Netbeans...), avoiding the design interface and writing code directly; you'll learn three times as much and avoid this kind of situations.

Comment: I'm trying to do both at the moment, but thank you. I used Eclipse for 4 years and I decided I'll keep to that when I want to use strictly Java. I'm only just getting into web design/development strongly right now, and Dreamweaver is kind of of blowing me away. But I agree I should see what else is out there. Thanks.

Comment: if you want you could use eclipse for php; there's a bundle called PDT or Php developer toolkit which is primarily setup for php. well you have to maximaize eclipse' potential which is using the workspaces. with workspaces you could have a host of other languages that eclipse support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

searching through the web via google search i stumbled upon a 2010 forum entry in adobe forums

here is the url [form variables don't appear in Bindings panel](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/748495)

That could include a host of all other unrelated issues

1.) is your wamp/xamp server on? or apache?

2.) is the php file you want to bind have a **`.php`** extension?

3.) Follow these steps

> Add **`<?php ?>`** anywhere in your code view
>   Save the document
>   Make sure that the document is saved as a file with ".php" extension
>   Refresh the Desgin View (click 2x on Live View)
>   Look at the Bindings tab, it should read exactly as Example 1 above
>   If not, close the document and reopen it again

4.) disable liveVIew

5.) Delete the **".mno"** document under the ( _notes ) folder. Just the "no name" document with the .mno extension will suffice. You will be able to create those form variable afterwards.

These were from a lynda.com tutorial with php and cs5

**Try these suggestions as mentioned in the URL**

Comment: This was actually my exactly problem. I'm following the same course on Lynda and I got stuck in the same spot. Sad to see it's still happening 2+ years and 2+ major versions of DW later. Thank you for finding that for me. I honestly could not get anything to come up for me that was relevant.

Comment: searching it first in google would really help you and it would enhance your research skills :D

Comment: That's what I meant. I searched for this in Google for a while and could not find anything specific to this problem.